# Scheduling posts via sql

Tags: posts, scheduled-posts

I got 10k posts with dates that are in the future. I imported my posts as a draft cause it seems quicker. I have used phpmyadmin to set the status of the posts to future with this sql command: `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_status = 'future' WHERE post_status != 'static';` The problem is when I go look at my posts they all say missed schedule when the date hasn't gone past yet! Is there any fix to fix the scheduling?

Comment: Note that scheduled posts are actually published by wp-cron entries. You cannot create those via SQL, with any degree of convenience at least. You might also hit issues having that many schedules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I can think of is a plug-in which will periodically take a draft and publish it for you.
http://wordpress.org/plugins/drafts-scheduler/
Maybe that will help you.

Update: above plugin has some issues so I wrote another one for this purpose.
http://www.superblogme.com/auto-post-scheduler/